# Big Query-how to compare the data weekly by pageviews,users in Big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to compare the pageviews,users,sessions in Big Query by weekly
so I want to compare 2019 (1st feb to 14th feb) data with 2020 (1st feb to 14th feb) and forecast it roughly for 2021 (1st feb to 14th feb)

can you please help me out how to see weekly data comparison in one single query?

so below I am only seeing the data by each day what I wanted to see is weekly data from 1st feb to 14th feb 2019 and see the data weekly with 2020 and 2021 data in same way

[image]

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @Popeye added a image above

Comment: "compare" is not a SQL operation.  Please explain the logic that you want to implement and the results you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I mean I wanted to see the weekly stats for 2019,2020 and predicted 2021 for the same time period.

Comment: @DivyangJain . . . Please explain where "predicted" values come from.  There is no SQL keyword "predict".

Answer (score 2):

Try the following in standard SQL:

```
with data as (
  select 1 as row, 'Life' as sitesection, '20190201' as `date`,   21940 as Pageviews, 19429 Users
  union all
  select 2 as row, 'Life' as sitesection, '20190202' as `date`,   29283 as Pageviews, 25910 Users
  union all
  select 1 as row, 'Life' as sitesection, '20200201' as `date`,   5 as Pageviews, 2 Users
  union all
  select 2 as row, 'Life' as sitesection, '20200202' as `date`,   6 as Pageviews, 3 Users
)
select  extract(YEAR from PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date)) as Year, 
        extract(WEEK from PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date)) as week, 
        sum(Pageviews) as totl_pageviews, 
        sum(Users) as total_users from data
group by extract(YEAR from PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date)), extract(WEEK from PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date))
```

It shows the total amount of page views and users grouped by year and week. I tried to simulate data in your picture in the `WITH` clause.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer by Kyrylo is good, though for most uses you probably wanting to show the first day of the week, maybe this:

```
with data as (
  select 1 as row, 'Life' as sitesection, date('2019-02-01') as `date`, 21940 as Pageviews, 19429 Users
  union all
  select 2 as row, 'Life' as sitesection, date('2019-02-02') as `date`, 29283 as Pageviews, 25910 Users
  union all
  select 1 as row, 'Life' as sitesection, date('2020-02-01') as `date`, 5 as Pageviews, 2 Users
  union all
  select 2 as row, 'Life' as sitesection, date('2020-02-02') as `date`, 6 as Pageviews, 3 Users
)
select  DATE_TRUNC(`date`, week) as first_day_of_week,
        sum(Pageviews) as totl_pageviews, 
        sum(Users) as total_users from data
group by first_day_of_week
```